# Raknet: Punchthrough attempt failed due to ID_NAT_TARGET_NOT_CONNECTED

Tags: connection, p2p, raknet

I am trying to test the NATCompleteClient and NATCompleteServer examples from [RakNet](https://github.com/facebookarchive/RakNet). I am able to get the NATCompleteServer to the update loop stage, but I am unable to get the NATCompleteClient to connect to the server:

```
Do you have a server running the NATCompleteServer project? (y/n): y
Executing UPNPFramework

Failed UPNPFramework
Proceeding to next stage.
Executing NatTypeDetectionFramework

Failed NatTypeDetectionFramework
Proceeding to next stage.
Executing NatPunchthoughClientFramework

Enter IP of system NatPunchthroughServer, or press enter for default: 
SOMESERVERIP
Enter port of system NatPunchthroughServer, or press enter for default: 61111
Connecting...
Enter RakNetGuid of the remote system, which should have already connected
to the server.
Or press enter to just listen.
702561543119132154

Calculating port stride from SOMESERVERIP|61111
INCAPABLE_PORT_STRIDE. My external ID is MYEXTERNALIP|50000
Starting ID_NAT_PUNCHTHROUGH_REQUEST to guid 702561543119132154.
Punchthrough attempt to guid 702561543119132154 failed due to 
ID_NAT_TARGET_NOT_CONNECTED.
Failed: ID_NAT_TARGET_NOT_CONNECTED

Failed NatPunchthoughClientFramework
Proceeding to next stage.
Executing Router2Framework

Failed Router2Framework
Proceeding to next stage.
Executing UDPProxyClientFramework

Failed UDPProxyClientFramework
Connectivity not possible. Exiting
```

I am running the NATCompleteServer on a digital ocean droplet not behind NAT. Also, I've tested on the droplet on canyouseeme.org and it shows that port 61111 on the server is not blocked.

How can I fix this problem?

*Note: Also, I know that RakNet is dead now ever since Facebook acquired it. What is the best place to ask questions and look for support since I am trying to integrate RakNet into my project?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since been able to fix this. I've realized that to make the NATPunch examples to work with Raknet, you need to run 2 clients and a server.

There is a new forum called SLikeNet which is trying to rebuild the community around RakNet. For people who need more help on Raknet setup and usage, use the forum [here](https://www.slikesoft.com/forum/). The mods have been extremely nice and helpful in assisting me to get this problem resolved